# What is x-tmpl?

Tags: html

Was looking for the answer on the net, but couldn't find anything. This little snack of code really frustrates me, as I can't understand it. (It's part of the plugin called: jQuery File Upload)

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <tr class="template-download fade">
    {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
    {% } else { %}
        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
        {% } %}</td>
        <td class="name">
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="delete">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
            <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
        </button>
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

- So, what type is `text/x-tmpl`?
- What are these `{%` and `%}` tags?
- What parser executes this code?
- ...

...but would like to know everything about this.

Comment: hey would you tell me how did you sent data with the upload like i want to send the place with the file

Comment: @Mayankswami: I don't get what you're trying to ask from me.

Comment: i think you have used the jquery file upload since . i want to know how to send form data with the file .

Comment: @Mayankswami: I think you should search for your question on this site, and if you don't find what you're looking for, then create a question.

Comment: this same code i have saw in the jquery file uploader so a aksed you sir

Comment: @Dyin How i can i pass the {%file.name%}  value to a php function?  Asked question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028006/how-to-pass-javascript-variable-into-php-function-as-parameters  but no one able to help me yet, please try to help me

Answer (score 65, accepted):

x-tmpl has no real meaning, it simply stops the browser from interpreting the script as javascript.

It's mostly used with jquery templates or [knockoutjs template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html).

At some point, a javascript data object will be used in conjunction with the template to render some html. The values in the data object will replace those marked with {%} and similar in the template, with some {%} sections reflecting code flow such as loops etc.

I'm not sure which templating library uses {%} however, it's not jquery templates, jsrender or knockout. You'd have to check what libraries are being referenced in the sample code.

Comment: I've found it here [JavaScript Templates](http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/). The script was referenced from this site. Now it all makes sense. Thank you for your brefing!

Comment: jQuery didn't work When I render HTML with x-tmpl. For example I have a checkbox that render inside x-tmpl. <label class="modifiericon btn"><input type="checkbox" id='seo'>SEO</label>. The script added inside html file. For example <script type="text/javascript"> $('#seo').change(function(){ if($(this).is(':checked')) { alert('hi'); }else{ alert('hello'); } } </script>

Answer (score 12):

> So, what type is text/x-tmpl?

A non-standard one. Looks like a template though.

> What are these {% and %} tags?

Part of the template language.

> What parser executes this code?

Probably one written in JavaScript and imported in another `<script>` element on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery-File-Upload` has a dependency on `JavaScript-Templates` which uses the nonstandard `text/x-tmpl` mime type

- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
- https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates

Comment: I had the same issue, but this plugin was the exact dependency for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

The code above references the project Django Jquery File Upload found here https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload

The {% %} are Django template tags. For more information visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/

These tags will be parsed by the django templating system

Comment: Doing some more research on this I found out that my answer was wrong. 
In this case the tags are been used by this Javascript library https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/fileupload/static/js/tmpl.min.js as a method to render HTML content on realtime based on the result of an AJAX operation.

Comment: These tags are not Django template tags, but Javascript Template Tags by Sebastian Tschan: http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/