# jQuery causing TemplateSyntaxError in Django

Tags: django, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, django-templates

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {
```

But I can't figure out how to escape it in Django, I've added `{% autoescape off %}` tags but still, no luck.

Here is the code causing the error:

```
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
        <td>
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
            </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
            </button>
            {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
    {% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
        <td></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">{%=locale.fileupload.error%}</span> {%=locale.fileupload.errors[file.error] || file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
        <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
        <td class="name">
            <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" rel="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
        </td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.destroy%}</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% } %}
```

I'm using the jQuery File Upload (jquery ui version) plugin. Can anyone explain to me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo it's pythonic, so it iterates like for loops in python: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements
So the for statement would look more like `{% for file in o.files %}` rather than your C-syntactical for loop.

Also see the official django documentation for for loops: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Looking at the rest of your code more closely, it seems like you have a lot of strange syntax in your template code (e.g. `{%=file.name%}` should be `{% file.name %}`, `{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}` should be `{% if not o.options.autoUpload %}`, etc.) You might check the djangobook chapter on templates:
http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/

Edit: The source uses template code syntax from [JavaScript Templates](http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/), not Django, which would seem to be the issue.

Comment: The strange syntax was already there when downloaded from https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/jquery-ui -- I have no clue what it is or why it's there.

Comment: Hmm. I'd have to look at the plug-in's source a lot more to figure out exactly what is going on and what can and cannot be changed, but django's template syntax is fairly straightforward, so I'd recommend changing the syntax in the template tags (`{% these %}`) to what's indicated on the above links, then continuing to troubleshoot compatibility issues from there.

Comment: Looks like the template code is for not django, but [JavaScript Templates](http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/). Here is an older question about the same code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025856/what-is-x-tmpl