# Form action in script tag

Tags: javascript, php, plugins

This is a part of my code.

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="">
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
<tr id="imgRow">
    <td>
    <input type="submit" name="copyImage" value="Copy Content" class="copy_content">
    <input type="hidden" name="postAction" value="copyFileContent">
    </td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" onClick="toggle(this);"></td>
</tr>
</script>
</form>
```

This code is working properly for same action page but when i sets action attribute of form like:

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="test.php">
```

Again it's working for same page means after submitting page is not going to action (test.php) page.
What may be reason?

If i use submit button above of **`<script>`** tag it works like:

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="test.php">
<input type="submit" name="copyImage" value="Copy Content" class="copy_content">
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It's in a pair of `<script>` tags with an unknown `type`, so the browser just ignores it. If you're not using it for templates, you should be able to safely remove the `script` tag, or maybe convert it to a `div` if you need to. See also: [What is x-tmpl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025856/what-is-x-tmpl)

Comment: @mc10
all attribute working fine like type=submit, method=post so action attribute should be work?