# What does this syntax pertain to in Railscast JQuery Upload tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

Watching the railscast for JQuery file upload I came across this scrpt when I was browsing the source code and I am unsure what it is exactly:

Paintings index.html.erb:

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
<div class="upload">
  {%=o.name%}
  <div class="progress"><div class="bar" style="width: 0%"></div></div>
</div>
</script>
```

I am mainly confused on what the `{%=.name%}` syntax is...

the entire source code can be found here:
https://github.com/railscasts/381-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/gallery-after/app/views/paintings/index.html.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is using  [JavaScript-Templates](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates) hence the syntax. Additionally, this other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025856/what-is-x-tmpl) explain the `text/x-tmpl` part.