# html inside js conflict tags with twig template

Tags: javascript, html, twig, slim

I am trying to make a simple project with multiple file uploads. I have created UploadHandler.php wich handles upload. And then in the view include the scripts and html like below. I am using twig template and slim framework. I am new at this and I am having some syntax issues.

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error text-danger"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary start" disabled>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                {% if (file.url) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
                {% } else { %}
                    <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                {% } %}
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="label label-danger">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (file.deleteUrl) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
            {% } else { %}
                <button class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
{% endblock %}
```

Th issue:

> Message: Unexpected character ";" in "uploads/list.twig" at line 67
>   which is the second line. Anyone that can help me?

Comment: You're totally mixing twig and php syntax. Read twig's docs again.

Answer (score 3):

Your example absolutely correct. The issue is that there is used js templating language and problem lays in conflict between twig format and text/x-tmpl.

I would suggest to move text/x-tmpl blocks in a seperate .js file and include it in a twig as a reference.

More details I found here
[What is x-tmpl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025856/what-is-x-tmpl)

UPDATE:
solution with seperate .js files didn't work. But there is another solution - make a seperate html file(uploadables-js.html) with those scripts including  tags. 
In .twig file insert link to this new file like this {{ source('uploadables-js.html') }}. IMPORTANT: include or use would not work

Answer (score -1):

Your `for` statement is wrong.

Try replacing your `for` with this:

```
{% for file in files %}
```

Documentation here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html