# How to display alert value inside nested table td

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am calling ajax in  a loop which is residing inside  as below,
i am able to alert the value correctly perfectly while iterating the loop, What i want is to show the same value in the `<td>` section, instead of giving alert, Is this possible?

```
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
    <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade">

            <td>
               <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                  <!----- Ajax function call -------->
                      var a= file.name;
                         $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://localhost/myappproject/trips_controller/showStatus/",
                            dataType: "text",
                            data: {image_name: a,trip_id: '2'},
                            success: function(msg){ 
                                  alert(msg);//how can i display this value in this place
                           }

                         });
            </td>

        </tr>
    {% } %}
    </script>
```

About **x-templ** used in this above code

- [what is x-templ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10025920/1684778)
- [Demo](https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/)

---

Please write to me, if you could not understand my question, i will try to explain you in some other way. From two two days i tried , and finally thought to ask Genius people who sees StckOverflow everyday :) –

Comment: Where you want to display the value to be?

Comment: there may be a better way, but you can embed the filename in a data attrib, then find that data attrib in the dom from the callback, and inject into the element that had the right attrib.

Comment: @Nayana_Das  Anyware in the same row where ajax is called. I already  mention in my question, i think

Comment: @dandavis Can you please post it as Answer, it will be very fruitful for me to understand

Comment: looks like the OP wants to do something like  `document.write()` but only in that `td`

Comment: @RahulDesai Yes, anywhere in the same row <tr> .... </tr>  , because i have to show result for each row, so off-course i have to show anywhere in the same row

Comment: @dandavis Please post a answer for me, as you mention in comment, it seems working. Please post & help me, it became so many hours i am wasting my energy and time to solve this problem.

Comment: what is the returned value ?

Comment: @Dwza  Returned value will be  "Yes" or  "NO"

Comment: and why don't you just simply return the value ? like: `return '<td>' + msg + '</td>';` or some like this because you are actually in the TD if i see this right :) so it could be `return '<span>' + msg + '</span>';`

Comment: @Dwza  i tried already using it did not displayed the value, i tried like `{%=msg%}`  instead of alert("..") & it didn't worked. can you post your answer, i will try that too..

Comment: i guess its because ajax than. Its asynchron :) so the value is returned to late...

Comment: see my answere and try this first and tell me the result :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65345/discussion-between-dwza-and-ashutosh).

Comment: @RahulDesai i tried as you suggested, but its printing the ajax response alone on ui by removing entire other UI outputs. How to show.  http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20141121-uq2p-24kb.jpg

Comment: @dandavis Can you help me, and post as answer what you mention in your comment, so that i can try it too. I tried all the four answer below But none of them worked

Answer (score 1):

AJAX =  **Asynchronous** **J**avascipt **A**nd **X**ml

**try this**

```
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">

        <td>
           <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
              <!----- Ajax function call -------->
              var a= file.name;
              $(document).ready(function (){  //run when page load is done
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost/myappproject/trips_controller/showStatus/",
                    dataType: "text",
                    data: {image_name: a,trip_id: '2'},
                    success: function(msg){ 
                          return '<span>' + msg + '</span>';
                    }

                 });
              });
        </td>

    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

**or make it synchron**

```
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">

        <td>
           <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
              <!----- Ajax function call -------->
                var a= file.name;
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "http://localhost/myappproject/trips_controller/showStatus/",
                   dataType: "text",
                   data: {image_name: a,trip_id: '2'},
                   success: function(msg){ 
                         return '<span>' + msg + '</span>';
                   },
                   async: false
                });
        </td>

    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

***Take care, if you would use this, you block/lock all other processings until its done... Same like doing a endless while in PHP. So if you request doesnt ends.. this will cause a little problem :)***

Comment: Sorry! Does not work, i replaced alert with `return '<span>' + msg + '</span>';` but it does not show any value on my ui

Comment: @Ashutosh its not only the return lane.... did you added this lane `$(document).ready(function (){ `? of course with the close bracket. Please copy the whole `<td>`-block

Comment: Yes tried now, with `$(document).ready..`, but still no luck. But again if i give alert on the same code instead of alert, its giving alert with correct value http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20141121-uf1q-44kb.jpg    AND the second code is also not showing value as we are expecting.. no luck still.. i tried other answer also, none of answer solve this problem, i am feeling very complex

Comment: in some cases it helps to change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` had some issues in PHP's PDO, may could be some... but you have a line in your screenshot that looks kind of wrong... should this really be `{% var a= file.name; ...` ? looks like a wrong escape for me... at least on the wrong position :)

Comment: the localhost is fine, because its calling on my server-side & returning correct results in success of ajax.. what kind of line you are saying ?,, it took long time, but still i am hoping to solve this issue, but for now i did this in this way http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20141121-iuaa-98kb.jpg   instead of showing status of each images on page load ... but it could be better if your answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
$('#TableID').append('<tr><td>' + msg+ '</td></tr>');
```

or

```
 $('<tr>').append('<td>' + msg+ '</td>');
```

Comment: i have updated my question with image, hope it gives you more clarity for understanding my question

Comment: If u put an id for tr tag and using that id, u can append the td, such as $('#trID').append('<td>' + msg+ '</td>');

Comment: This is plugin,  & its drectly showing images from the folder, if its from my Table then i could have put id in tr.. But since its plugin(https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html) , I used the same code from  https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-9.5-with-CodeIgniter-2.1.4  .If you see you might be able to find something

Comment: I tried both the  way you posted but It is not showing output , Does not works. http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20141121-mdn9-22kb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I change my mind, after reading posts i modify my answer do you check this out?

Add this code at the top of your html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxCall(fileName, index) {
       $("#inner-file-msg-" + index).html("initializing...");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/myappproject/trips_controller/showStatus/",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {image_name: fileName,trip_id: '2'},
                success: function(msg){ 
                    $("#inner-file-msg-" + index).html(msg);
                }
            });
    }
</script>
```

Then this is your template :

```
 <script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade">
            <td>
                <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
                <span id="inner-file-msg-{%=i%}"></span>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    ajaxCall("{%=file.name%}", "{%=i%}");
                <\/script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% } %}
</script>
```

Ps : I am not sure about </script> line if it wont work can you change this line to

Comment: i edited my post. I try my new answer where demo page that you gave and it worked. Can you try?

Comment: Hi, Not showing value, i tried  your code but its showing, as http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20141121-fcxd-33kb.jpg

Comment: Again tested after modifying the code, but still its not showing value,... http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20141121-luta-78kb.jpg

Comment: Can you help me with other solution please, the above solution did not worked. only the alert message i am able show ... I was in office that time when you posted this question, so could not able to test you immediately, but now i tested its not working.

Comment: Output coming with blank: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20141121-lxne-31kb.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
   <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
           <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
           <span id="status-{%=i%}">loading...</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    //JavaScript function call- use x-templ syntax
     showStatus(file.name,i);                        
{% } %}
</script>
<script>
function showStatus(name, id){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/myappproject/trips_controller/showStatus/",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {image_name: a,trip_id: '2'},
            success: function(msg){ 
                  $('#status-'+id).html(msg);//or use native innerHTML prop
           }
         });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do i have to keep this entire code inside the loop ? or  the function `showStatus` will be outside of the loop, Can you please add the `<tr> <td>` attribute also , so that it will make more clear

Comment: showStatus has to be outside of loop. Just add tr, td around the span.

Comment: sorry, not working.   the `showStatus` function is not getting called at all,  i tried giving alert there ..

Comment: can you try by directly calling $.ajax instead of making showStatus call?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests are asynchronous, so their results are handled much later, when the DOM has already been constructed. There's no way (except making the request synchronous, which I won't even mention here further) to "return the HTML at the spot where the request was called", as you're trying to do. This means that there's no reason to place the request call inside the table cell at all. You just need to assign some identifiers to your table cells, so that you're able to find them later and change their contents. Then you perform your AJAX calls in one place somewhere. I'm not sure about the exact syntax of the library you're using, but it'll look something like this:

```
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
           <span>{%=file.name%}</span>
           <span id="file-{%=file.name%}-status"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <!----- Ajax function call -------->
    (function (file) {
        $.ajax({
            // ...
            success: function (msg){
                $('#file-' + file.name + '-status').html(msg);
            }
        });
    })(file);
{% } %}
```

Just a reminder - the sample above is pseudo-code. You might need to make small adjustments to make it work with the library you're using.