# How to add "filemdate" to the file download list

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

To show "filemtime" in the file list, I added the following [JavaScript Templates](http://blueimp.github.com/JavaScript-Templates/) code to "index.html":

```
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
  <td>
    <span class="size">
       {%=file.mtime%}
    </span>
  </td>
{% } %}
```

I tried:

1. `{%=file.mtime%}`
2. `{%=file.filemtime%}`
3. `{%=file.gmtime%}`

to no avail.

Comment: I assume you're using some preprocessor language that I don't recognize, because `{%` and the like are not even slightly HTML, nor yet JS.

Comment: umm.. may be i think these language used in jquery.
 
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">

Comment: Ah. The comments on http://stackoverflow.com/a/10025920/4099598 indicate it's not even part of jQuery, never mind JS itself; it's used by blueimp's Javascript Templates.

Comment: @NathanTuggy thank you.. but i want know about how to get a filemtime.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10025856/4447216 also use file.name , file.url and file.size but file.mtime doesn't work. 
sorry.. my english is bad..